# Convert Json with sub fields to CSV in python

Tags: python, json, csv, tablib

I have a file with sample JSON output looks as below:
jsonoutput.txt file:

```
[{"fruit": "orange", "id":1, "countries": ["Portugal"], "color": "Orange"}

{"fruit": "apple", "id":2, "countries": ["Portugal"], "color": "red"}]
```

I need the output csv as (excel file):

```
fruit id countries color
orange 1 Portugal Orange
apple 2  Spain     red
```

Now, I am getting as 
fruit id countries     color
orange 1 [u'Portugal'] Orange
apple 2  [u'Spain']      red

How can I remove [] , u and '' from the column countries?

`print (json.dumps(fruits))` --gives me in json output

This is what I have tried to convert json to xlsx:

```
data= tablib.Dataset(headers=('Fruit','id','Countries','Color'))
importfile = 'jsonoutput.txt'
data.json = open(importfile. 'r').read()
data_export = data.export('xlsx')
with open('output.xlsx','wb') as f:
    f.write(data_export)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

d = [
    {"fruit": "orange", "id":1, "countries": ["Portugal"], "color": "Orange"},
    {"fruit": "apple", "id":2, "countries": ["Portugal"], "color": "red"}
]

df = pd.concat([json_normalize(d[i]) for i in range(len(d))], ignore_index=True)
df['countries'] = df['countries'].str.join(' ')
```

---

```py
    fruit   id  countries   color
0   orange  1   Portugal    Orange
1   apple   2   Portugal    red
```

---

to save it as `.xlsx` file, use:

```py
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', index=False)
```

---

**EDIT:**

`json_normalize` is a function that normalizes semi-structured JSON data into a flat table.

I actually realised now that my code could be simplified to:

```py
df = json_normalize(d) # no need for `pd.concat`

### Output:
#   fruit   id  countries   color
# 0 orange  1   ['Portugal']    Orange
# 1 apple   2   ['Portugal']    red
```

To remove `[]` from `countries` column, I used [`pandas.Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), which is `pandas`' equivalent to Python's [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

It's needed since initially `countries` column is a list containing elements

```py
df['countries'] = df['countries'].str.join(' ')
```

`countries` column is no longer a list once you join items:

```py
    fruit   id  countries   color
0   orange  1   Portugal    Orange
1   apple   2   Portugal    red
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you please explain the last 2 commands to me, as I am very new to pandas.